# How to create a Poller in jzmq Java bindings for ZeroMQ?

Tags: zeromq, jzmq

I am going through the examples on the ZeroMQ website and all the Java examples don't work for the jzmq library.  I think they work with the other Java implementation but the project I am working on is using jzmq.  Are there examples anywhere for JZMQ?

Specifically, how do you create a Poller?  The example has:

```
context.createPoller(2);
```

There is a method on the context that is depreciated:

```
context.getContext().poller();
```

And says to use the constructor but the ZMQ.Poller constructor is protected.

How are you supposed to construct one?

Answer (score 0):

I found a code sample that creates a poller using JZMQ 3.1.0 library.  It is just a little different than the other java API.

```
   //You use the constructor that takes the number of pollers
   ZMQ.Poller poller = new ZMQ.Poller(2);
   //then you register your socket contexts
   int id1 = poller.register(socket1, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
   int id2 = poller.register(socket2, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
```

Hope this helps someone else.